# Taxonomy Term Page is showing the same body for all nodes

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'm converting my old site to drupal and updating my Teaser view mode so that the nodes appear as I want them on the Taxonomy Term page.

http://dev.inadaydevelopment.com/tags/ipad

The problem is that the Body field for all of the nodes is showing up with the same text. The nodes do not have the same body text, so I have no idea how or why all of these Teasers are showing the same body text.

Any idea?

Comment: what is your `view` settings, problem might be there...

Comment: What settings do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Some poorly written jQuery was dynamically swapping out the body tags. Blerg.